# Problem with paypal integration with iphone

Tags: iphone

Actually i am trying to execute following code to implement paypal...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];
}


-(IBAction)payPal:(id)sender
{
    PayPal *payObject=[PayPal getInstance];
    PayPalPayment *obj=[[PayPalPayment alloc]init];
    obj.recipient=@"priyankasaroha@gmail.com";
    obj.paymentCurrency=@"USD";
    obj.description=@"Teddy Bear";
    obj.merchantName=@"Priyanka";
    obj.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"]; 
    [payObject checkoutWithPayment:obj];        
}
```

bt wen i m trying to run this getting error during linking time with .o files of mobile payment library..like "  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSCharacterSet", referenced from:
                     objc-class-ref-to-NSCharacterSet in libPayPalMEP.a(PPUtils.o)"
please tell me how to solve dis ..